# AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'point'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am transforming a point from source frame to target frame using tf2. Below is the code snippet:

```
import tf2_ros
import tf2_geometry_msgs

transform = tf_buffer.lookup_transform(target_frame, source_frame, rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(1.0))
pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point(point_wrt_kinect, transform)
print pose_transformed
```

It throws following error:

```
  pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point(point_wrt_kinect, transform)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py", line 59, in do_transform_point
    p = transform_to_kdl(transform) * PyKDL.Vector(point.point.x, point.point.y, point.point.z)
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'point'
```

The point is defined as follows:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
point_wrt_kinect = Point()
point_wrt_kinect.x = -0.41
point_wrt_kinect.y = -0.13
point_wrt_kinect.z =  0.77
```

However, since I am getting the above error. So I redefined the point as follows

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
class MyPoint():
    def __init__(self):
        self.point = Point()
```

And then initialize the point as below:

```
point_wrt_kinect = MyPoint()
point_wrt_kinect.point = Point(-0.41, -0.13, 0.77)
```

It works! However is a there better way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275165/attributeerror:-%27point%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27point%27/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-11-07**:
BTW: That's a really well formulated question. It contains all the info and also your current solution. (and pose_transformed should be point_stamped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the author had a PointStamped in mind when implementing the function. So you could could do something like

```
ps = geometry_msgs.msg.PointStamped(point=point_wrt_kinect)
pose_transformed = tf2_geometry_msgs.do_transform_point(ps, transform)
```

The code for the function is here: [https://github.com/ros/geometry2/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_geometry_msgs/src/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py)

The function only uses the point-member of the passed point-variable so it for example does not check if the frame-id of a passed PointStamped-variable would fit to the frames of the transformation (the frame is here used to set the resulting frame of the returned PoseStamped).

So in the end, *do_transform_point* looks like it's processing objects with Headers but ignores them and only works on the raw points and transformation.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-07**:
Suggestion: give it a `stamp` and `frame_id` as well. Methods that take a `PointStamped` will probably assume that they can use the `header.stamp` and `header.frame_id` fields to lookup TF frames.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-11-07**:
I expanded the answer a bit, the function ignores the frame of the Point. I think the function should print at least a warning if point_st.header.frame_id != transform.child_frame_id (if the point_st has a frame_id)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-07**:
My comment was meant more for the 'general case' where one invokes methods that take `*Stamped` versions of objects.

I can see why this particular method wouldn't look at `stamp`, as you're already passing in the `transform`. But checking for the `frame_id` would perhaps be nice, as you write.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2017-11-07**:
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-11-07**:
I opened an Issue: https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/273